# Block unwanted/pop-up Ads on iOS browsers

Tags: iphone, safari, google-chrome

So these gift-card Ads seem to be giving me trouble for some reason lately, and it seems like its okay on Safari on iOS but on Google Chrome on iOS,  there seems to be no way to get rid of them.

Other than tapping **Ok** (which I don't think I have ever done with one of these scam popups) - what do I do?

[image]

Comment: Are you using sketchy sites? *yes* Don't use sketchy sites.

Comment: what are sketchy sites?

Comment: Well apparently I am using sketch sites for some reason right now. Usually I never do but sometimes it just happens, sites that seem to do this are “news” sites related to tech and health which look innocent from the google page, and the google ranking is high and also are AMP

Answer (score 1):

The best suggestion here is to not open sketchy sites.

Alternatively, you can install one of the many available content blocker or ad blocker apps on the app store. Starting with iOS 9, Apple has started approving Ad blocker apps on the iOS App Store.

Search for "Ad Blocker" on App Store. There are various such free and paid apps available on the App Store.

Comment: For some reason sketchy sites have been showing up higher in the google search ranking, and with amp it makes it seem like these sites are okay because they are around other more trusted websites

Answer (score 0):

You should try the free app [MalwareBytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/ios/). This will scan your system for info related to malware and clean your system of things like you describe. As I said earlier the personal copy for the Mac is free. There is an ios version as shown by the link.

Comment: OP appears to be facing the issue on iOS. Figured out from the site that Malwarebytes has an [iOS app](https://www.malwarebytes.com/ios/) as well.

Comment: You may wish to edit your answer and update the hyperlink to the iOS client's web-page.

Comment: why the downvote.  works on ios...